# mitmproxy request URL redirection does not work

Tags: attacks, man-in-the-middle, proxy, url-redirection, tls-intercept

I need to redirect the user's request in such a way when a user enters: https://a.com the mitmproxy redirect it to: https://www.newsite.com/?somepage

From a previous post, I found this script in the 3rd answer:

```
import mitmproxy
from mitmproxy import http

def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.url == 'https://a.com':
        flow.request.host = 'www.newsite.com'
        flow.request.path = '/?somepage'
```

But it does not work. The client's browser (Chrome) just hangs. However, if I tried something close (different code though) but without https:// the redirection works, but the user must not enter https:// which I do not want, and also, it does not redirect to a new host and path, i.e. I have to remove the /?somepage from the new URL.

Here is the script (from mitmproxy GitHub's page) that works without the user typing https:// and without new URL's path:

```
import mitmproxy
from mitmproxy import http
def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    # pretty_host takes the "Host" header of the request into account,
    # which is useful in transparent mode where we usually only have the IP
    # otherwise.
    if flow.request.pretty_host == "a.com":
        flow.request.host = "www.newsite.com"
```

What is the problem? How to fix my script such that it directs the user's request with https:// (e.g. https://a.com) to a new URL with a path (https://newsite.com/?somepage)

Comment: What mode is mitmproxy in (transparent or not?)? What do you get if you `curl -v` instead of using a browser?

Comment: I use normal mode: mitmproxy -s redirect.py